# Dbus python simple example

Tags: python-2.7, dbus

I've been looking for an example of a simple server - client dbus method calling (a client that calls a simple hello world method on the server) but all I've found until now it's incomplete and bad explained. Could someone suggest me where to find a good example?

For now I've read the official documentation:

http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html

which has some examples but not a full one.

Thankyou

Comment: There are 2 complete examples under "Interfaces and methods".

Comment: Thankyou, I've found the example in the GIT repo of dbus since no link is available on the tutorial page. (http://cgit.freedesktop.org/dbus/dbus-python/tree/examples/example-client.py)

Comment: You can view a simple example in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21793826/simple-but-specific-listener-and-sender-python-3-dbus-example